# How do you define a file response as a Message

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto, proto3

I'm using `proto` to define a REST service

In my service, I'm trying to document that a service responds with a file.

I've looked through here https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/src/google/protobuf but couldn't find anything that looked like a file.

```proto
service SomeService {
    rpc GetStaticAsset(GetMessageRequest) returns (FileAsset) {
        option (google.api.http) = {
            get: "/static/{assetName}"
        };
    }
}

message FileAsset {
    ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://ops.tips/blog/sending-files-via-grpc):

```
message Chunk {
    bytes Content = 1;
}
```